# Changing duplicated object's texture effects the first object's

Tags: texturing, materials, objects

I tried to copy a mesh, and when I changed its texture so did the source mesh.
How come when I create a mesh duplicate and change the texture, the original mesh's texture changes as well?

Answer (score 4):

The meshes share the same texture. You have to duplicate the texture as well by clicking on that number next to the name in that field where you select the texture. I think it says "make single user copy" on mouseover (don't have Blender open right now)

Comment: problem can be the same, but about the material. Duplicates share the same material. same solution but for material name.